# AWS support - Need help / tips to upload Laravel 5.3 project on EC2 free tier

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I am in need of steps I should follow to upload a project I have created using Laravel 5.3.

I am using AWS EC2 free tier, and i cannot find suitable resources / guides online. So will greatly appreciate all help / guidance here.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to do change depending on OS. But a basic google search gave many links, including laracasts forum discussion.
[Deploying laravel to EC2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/deploying-laravel-to-ec2)

Few things to keep in mind.

- need to change root directory to public folder of laravel project
- enable permissions for storage folder to enable logging
- mod rewrite should be enabled.